# One line of JS code is breaking within Wordpress. Not sure why

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

```
$(function(){
  $(".youtubeThumb").each(function(){
      $(this).bind('click touchstart', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

      var ytLink = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
      //the line below is what keeps breaking
      var ytLink = ytLink.split('/vi/').pop().split('/').shift();
      var ytPlayList = 'PLDMZzXD-QCET2VK_l9aGhOXNMZjWjzI0g';

      $('.youtubeEmbed iframe').attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/'+ytLink+'?list='+ytPlayList+'&wmode=transparent&autoplay=1');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.youtubeEmbed').offset().top
    }, 600);
      })
   })
});

//Error Below from console
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined ?page_id=28:169(anonymous function) ?       page_id=28:169n.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.1.min.js?ver=2.1.1:3r.handle
```

I have never really worked with wordpress before so I could be way off on what I am trying to do.
The link to the page is http://twistedmess.com/?page_id=28

and as you see here on a separate page the code works fine http://schottmandesign.com/test3

I have tried putting the script in a separate js file and then putting it into the header.php, putting it into the actual page itself, and right now it is being contained in a shortcode plugin that I am then calling on the actual page. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does `console.log(ytlink, ytLink.split('/vi/').pop())` return? Because that error message suggests it should be `undefined`, which means the break occurs in the line above, and `ytlink` isn't found.

Comment: console.log(ytLink.split('/vi/').pop())


Uncaught ReferenceError: ytLink is not defined VM2615:2(anonymous function) VM2615:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn

VM2583:732InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap 

VM2583:665InjectedScript.evaluate

Comment: So work backwards and establish why `ytlink` is `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want instead of children, is find. you want to look recursively through all the elements in the jquery object. children is only one level below parent deep. see this fiddle for a toy example http://jsfiddle.net/gq36et5x/1.

instead your code should look like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".youtubeThumb").each(function(){
  $(this).bind('click touchstart', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

  var ytLink = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  //the line below is what keeps breaking
  var ytLink = ytLink.split('/vi/').pop().split('/').shift();
  var ytPlayList = 'PLDMZzXD-QCET2VK_l9aGhOXNMZjWjzI0g';

  $('.youtubeEmbed iframe').attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/'+ytLink+'?list='+ytPlayList+'&wmode=transparent&autoplay=1');

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.youtubeEmbed').offset().top
}, 600);
  })
  })
});
```

also, its not necessary to run the each loop to bind to click event. you could just slim things down this way:

```
$(function(){
  $(".youtubeThumb").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ytLink, ytPlaylist; 
    ytPlaylist = 'PLDMZzXD-QCET2VK_l9aGhOXNMZjWjzI0g';
    ytLink = $(this).find('img').attr('src').split('/vi/').pop().split('/').shift();

    $('.youtubeEmbed iframe').attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/'+ytLink+'?list='+ytPlayList+'&wmode=transparent&autoplay=1');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.youtubeEmbed').offset().top}, 600);})
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The img tag is not a direct child of the .youtubeThumb element, therefore change `children` to `find`. Moreover, `find` will return an array of elements (or an empty array if there are no matches), so, you will need to check the content of what `find` returns before you try to access the `src` attribute;

```
var ytThumb = $(this).find('img');
if (ytThumb.length > 0) {
    var ytLink = ytThumb[0].attr('src');
    // ... the rest of the code
}
```

EDIT: Got answered by gabereal in the meantime.